# Centering content vertically and horizontally, the browser doesn't allow scrolling

Tags: css, css-position, vertical-alignment, centering, alignment

I'm using the following css to center my content both vertically and horizontally; the problem is that when you minimize the browser to make it smaller than the content `div`, it continues to center but without the ability to scroll. The content just cuts off at the top.

```
#splash-centre-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 550px;
  width: 760px;
  min-height: 550px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: -310px 0 0 -400px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you position something as `absolute` you pull it out of the flow of the page, it doesn't "take up space".

You want to apply `min-width` and `min-height` to `body` (or its container) so that when the screen gets too small, the element that the splash screen is centered within will never get smaller than the splash screen and thus won't go off screen.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/U42vg/2/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="spacer">
    <div id="splash-centre-container">abc</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { 
    min-width:760px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:550px;
    position:relative;
}
#splash-centre-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 550px;
    width: 760px;
    margin: -275px 0 0 -380px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Took me a while to get the demo going :P

Comment: @Adam how does this center vertically?  didn't you just ask me to center it vertically?

Comment: @btevfik The problem was that when the screen size was getting too small the centered splash screen would go off screen. It's still centered in my screenshot it's just scrolled to the left.

Comment: @Tyriar i thought he was asking like what i have. center the div in the middle of the page

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
#splash-centre-container {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/XMNTM/

Comment: I don't think this centers it vertically.

Comment: then i suppose you want something like this

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier posted the best solution I could find [here in 2009](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/).  I think it's the best because it centers content vertically and horizontally, *and* it allows for dynamic height (the other answers posted here depend upon fixed heights, which is unnecessarily limiting) plus scrolling for smaller screens.  That's great for creating centered inline forms that replace modal pop-ups.

I cleaned up and converted that code to a Sass mixin so you can easily customize the form width (tip: add form element CSS and associated variables to the Sass mixin because your form element widths will be constrained within the centered inline form).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alight3874/0n3hxow5/)

**SCSS**

```
html,
body,
form {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@mixin CenteredInlineForm( $ContainerSetName, $formWidth) {
  div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredForm {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: #{($formWidth + 15)}px;
    div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredFormContentContainer {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredFormContent {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        border: 3px solid darkgrey;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding: 15px;
      }
    }
  }
  *:first-child + html div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredForm {
    position: relative;
  }
  /*ie6 Support: */
  /* * html div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredForm{position:relative;} */
  *:first-child + html div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredFormContentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  }
  /*ie6 Only: */
  /* * html div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredFormContentContainer{position:absolute;top:50%;} */
  *:first-child + html div.#{$ContainerSetName}_CenteredFormContent {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
  }
}

@include CenteredInlineForm(UserInfoInput, 400);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="UserInfoInput_CenteredForm">
  <div class="UserInfoInput_CenteredFormContentContainer">
    <div class="UserInfoInput_CenteredFormContent">
      <p>
        Content or form labels/inputs
      </p>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```